# Firestore subscribe to removed docs only

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

The docs say:

> The snapshot handler will receive a new query snapshot every time the query results change (that is, when a document is added, removed, or modified).

Is it possible to pass an option to the onSnapshot function that would set up a listener that would get only when an item gets deleted?

I know about docChanges() api but if I use that I'll be paying for creates, removes and modifications to doc, and I'm only interested in the removed documents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to only listen for document removals in a Firestore query/snapshot listener through the SDKs. The best you can do is only respond to the `removed` event in [your handler](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#view_changes_between_snapshots), but the snapshot will still have all documents.

It's an interesting request though, so you might want to [file a feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/report). It's not a common request though, so I don't think it'll be prioritized right away.

Alternatively, you **can** [write a Cloud Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events) that only responds to Firestore document deletion.